# Inequality with powers of 2

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, integers, substitution, muirhead-inequality

If $m,n$ and $p $ are positive integers show that :
$$\frac{2^{mn}}{p}+\frac{2^{np}}{m}+\frac{2^{pm}}{n}\geq 2(m+n+p).$$
I tried using Bernoulli inequality and then Hölder's, but I cannot prove this inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $k\ge 1 \implies 2^k\geq 2k$ then

$$\frac{2^{mn}}{p}+\frac{2^{np}}{m}+\frac{2^{pm}}{n}\geq \frac{2{mn}}{p}+\frac{2{np}}{m}+\frac{2{pm}}{n}\geq 2(m+n+p)$$

which is true by [Muirhead's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality) since

$$\frac{{mn}}{p}+\frac{{np}}{m}+\frac{{pm}}{n}\geq m+n+p \iff m^2n^2+n^2p^2+p^2n^2\geq m^2np+n^2mp+p^2mn$$

Comment: Nice solution! +1

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! I really appreciate your work here. Maybe I can eliminate the special case and refer to $2^k>2k$, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you can, of course. It solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks Michael!

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. It's easier than I thought.

Comment: You are welcome. Bye!

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{{mn}}{p}+\frac{{np}}{m}+\frac{{pm}}{n}\geq m+n+p$$ 
$$\frac{(mn)^2}{mnp}+\frac{(np)^2}{mnp}+\frac{(pm)^2}{mnp}\geq \frac{(mn+np+pm)^2}{3mnp}$$ $$\frac{(mn+np+pm)^2}{3mnp} \geq m+n+p$$  $$(mn-np)^2+(np-pm)^2+(pm-mn)^2 \geq 0$$

Comment: Sorry but I can't follow all the step you are doing, in any case the first inequality implies for sure the last (it can be also deived multiplying both sides for 2mnp).

Comment: Your inequality was great $2 ^k\geq 2k$. The rest is just Holder and then S.O.S.